# Can you use dictionary( text) to regex tokenization?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I was wondering if we can use a text files as a means for tokenization. For example let's say there is a file(dictionary) and you want to tokenize you check first dictionary to tokenize.

Eg:

Dict_list = [environment test, apple cat, test rest]

Text : The environment test is the best apple in the world apple cat is the test rest.

Assume the text list is big and dict is also big, so if we want to tokenize it would tokenize by spaces however I need to tokenize whole text however I want to check dict_list to see if that should be one token.

so the token should be:

Token : "The", "environment test", "is", "the", "best apple", "in", "the", "world", "apple cat", "is", "the", "test rest".

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No, it makes no sense. Do you have some code, expected results and actual results? Or is this a philosophical question.

Comment: @Sam This is your solution: http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html

Comment: @RobertB, I have a text document which I need to tokenize. We can't tokenize the document using normal regex/tokenizer so I need a way to tokenize this text. I believe it would be easier if I could combine regex and dictionary. My question was if that is possible.

Comment: @mertyildiran, I already checked this out. This is not something that will help me.

Comment: It is not clear why a 'normal tokenizer' isn't applicable. Also not clear what you mean by "regex and dictionary."  Are you saying you want to look words up in a dictionary, like Websters Dictionary, not a Python 'dict'?

Comment: @RobertB, Yes that's what I mean. That being said I was trying to use Multi-Word Expression tokenizer. However, when I use from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer. I get an error ImportError: cannot import name 'MWETokenizer' . Do you know what is causing this error. I am using python 3.4

Comment: @Sam Check out my answer. It works perfectly fine for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way but a workaround:

Python3 version:

```
from nltk.tokenize import regexp_tokenize

sent = "I like apple fruit but grape fruit more"
dict_list = ["apple fruit", "grape fruit"]
newdict = {}
for item in dict_list:
    dk = item.replace(" ", "_")
    newdict[item] = dk

for key, val in newdict.items():
    if key in sent:
        sent = sent.replace(key, val)

res = regexp_tokenize(sent, pattern='\S+')
print(res)
```

Output:

['I', 'like', 'apple_fruit', 'but', 'grape_fruit', 'more']

You can then replace all the underscores with space if you wish.

Comment: Hi Kmario, I see you are using dictionary, can I do the same thing with list instead? instead of dict: i need list: Other than that  this is what I am looking for.

Comment: hi sam! Of course you can but using dictionary will be fast since the run time complexity for lookup is O(1).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I need to use the list because the "dictionary" I am talking about is in list format. When I say dictionary, I want to use it as a normal dictionary to look into it to tokenize properly

Answer (score 2):

With [nltk.tokenize](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) package you can easily do this. For example:

```
>>> tokenizer.tokenize('Testing testing testing one two three'.split())
['Testing', 'testing', 'testing', 'one', 'two', 'three']

>>> tokenizer = MWETokenizer([('hors', "d'oeuvre")], separator='+')
>>> tokenizer.tokenize("An hors d'oeuvre tonight, sir?".split())
['An', "hors+d'oeuvre", 'tonight,', 'sir?']
```

Comment: This is little different than I was looking for. Notice how I don't need + and also I was wondering if we can use other regex expression with the dictionary. Is it possible to combine regex and the dictionary?

Comment: I think this is a pretty good solution for you. The '+' is in the token, not in the source.  If you don't like it, change it or take it out.

Comment: @mertyiliran, I was trying to use Multi-Word Expression tokenizer. However, when I use from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer. I get an error ImportError: cannot import name 'MWETokenizer' . Do you know what is causing this error. I am using python 3.4

Comment: @mertyildiran, I have NLTK libary yet I get that error.

Comment: @Sam I'm not sure what is the problem